# LinearSolve in wolfram mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have problem with linearsolve in mathematica. I have a system like Mx=A. M is 3x2 matrix with complex elements. x is 2x1 matrix with elements x1 and x2. A is 3x1 matrix with complex elements. So when I use `LinearSolve[M,A]`, it always gives "LinearSolve::nosol: Linear equation encountered that has no solution.". Why?

Comment: Ask yourself: How would you invert that 3x2 matrix?  If the answer is "I can't", you'll be a long way towards understanding what LinearSolve is telling you.

Comment: Maybe you need SVD or some other solver.

Comment: I think linear algebra would tell you that there is no solution if the null space of the matrix is not empty.

Comment: Thank you duffmo the problem is taking the matrix 3x2, so 2x2 matrix solved my problem.